# Android Studio - Constraint Layout Vs Relative Layout Which Is Better?

Tags: android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

Why does the items get misplaced in constraint layout, is constraint layout better than relative layout (Newbie Here) Which one is recommended

Comment: Use ConstraintLayout, it is recommended. See [Build Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: Hm but when i create an Activity in a Constraint Layout, the items get misplaced during run time why is that so? Any solutions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " but when I create an Activity in a Constraint Layout, the items get
>   misplaced during runtime why is that so?"

This happens because you must not be adding all the required constraints for your views.

For example: If your view has only it's top aligned to another view, on rendering, it may move anywhere horizontally since it's left or right isn't aligned.

I suggest that you look into the official documentation and examples. You could also search for YouTube tutorials on ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Thank you Rohan Taneja, yes i was not constraining the items to top, bottom, left and right, now i get it, Thank u once again...

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout is better than the relative layout as it provides you the both feature of relative layout and the linearlayout. you can provide the weight to views in coordinatorlayout which was absent in the relative Layout to do so earlier we need to add another layer of a linearlayout